# Use/(change to) bash shell only if is present on the machine

Tags: bash

I'm use `.login` file to change the shell on login and do other modifications.

If I try to `ssh` from this machine to another machine(that use shareable profile) that doesn't have bash(has tcsh) I will get an error, and the connection is closed.

How can I check if bash exist, only if exists make the changes.

Comment: chsh -l will list the shells available to you

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @Raman, on which `chsh` implementations?  It's certainly not a recognised flag for the one in `passwd` version 4.7.

Comment: chsh as part of util-linux-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64 https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh

Answer (score 0):

Just test whether it exists before executing it.  For example:

```
test -x /bin/bash && exec /bin/bash -l
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh user@host -tt 'sh -c "test -x /bin/bash && exec /bin/bash -l"'`

`-tt` = force to allocate a terminal

Also you can check on the remote machine if bash is allowed to be a login shell in `/etc/shells/`